# ORDER BY clause based on value - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in a MySQL database.

One of the columns is entitled `Failed` and some rows have the value `Yes` in them.

How do I order my `SELECT` query so it shows the rows that have no value first and then shows the ones with `Yes` as the value at the end?

Comment: What do you meant by no value ? is it empty string ?

Comment: Yes, an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use ASC or DESC when ordering on the field(s) you wish to order by.  In this case try:

```
ORDER BY Failed ASC
```

Comment: Ooooh that's nice & tidy. Thanks, Tom - will give it a whirl :-)

Comment: Also, is it possible to have a 2nd ORDER BY, should there be no values in the `Failed`. Like `id DESC`?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk You bet!  Just add the field like this: order by Failed ASC, id DESC.  Just follow each field with a comma.

Comment: I should add the ordering takes place in order of precedence from left to right, so first field on left is ordered then the next, etc. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `CASE` in `Order by`

```
Order by case when col <> 'yes' then 2 else 1 end
```